# PHP how to print proper column td1 td2 td3 output?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to output a table using php variables like this:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$var1."</td>";
echo "<td>".$var2."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

It works fine if both variables exist.. but if $var1 is null, the $var2 value is outputted to the firs column in the HTML table.
Is there a way to properly output the columns by naming them?
P.S: I can't do "if $var == NULL ...." for some coding reasons. I want to control the HTML output if possible.

Comment: "if $var == NULL ...." use is_null() ?

Comment: why can't you use a conditional? Doesn't really make sense that you can't if you ask me...

Comment: @leeeb: `=== null` is absolutely fine.

Comment: can you add a space before </td>?

Comment: actually, i don't know why. I am using xpath() to get the variables and it seems that if it's empty, something goes wrong and it's not NULL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$var1."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>".$var2."&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: i think this is a simple and a nice workaround! Why didn't i think of that? :)

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @leeb above, do you want something like this:

```
echo "<td>" . isset($var1)?$var1:"" . "</td>";
```

Comment: I am using xpath() to get the variables and it seems that if it's empty, something goes wrong and it's not NULL